# Общий глагол-связка для двух простых предложений

Tags: пунктуация

Будут, великан идти коротким шагом, чтобы не опережать, а карлик широким, чтобы не отставать

Стоит ли отделять запятой общий глагол-связку "будут"? Возможна ли такая конструкция?

Comment: А может, карлик широким?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то Вы тут, мне кажется, перемудрили.

Возможно написать таким образом.
***Будет*** великан идти коротким шагом, чтобы не опережать, а карлик — [будет идти] *широким, чтобы не отставать.*

Или таким.
Будут они идти [так]: великан — коротким шагом, чтобы не опережать, а карлик — широким, чтобы не отставать.

Или таким.
И будут они идти: коротким шагом — великан, чтобы не опережать, а широким — карлик, чтобы не отставать.

Comment: А почему в первом приведенном вами варианте "будет" стоит в единственном?

Comment: Главное предложение — Будет идти великан. А ЧТО будет делать кто-то другой (или другие) и каким образом — это объясняется во второй части предложения.